# Is it bad practice to name a class with a facade suffix?

Tags: coding-style

Is it bad practice to name classes after the façade pattern?

```
public class OrderFacade {}
public class InvoiceFacade {}
public class ThingFacade {} ...
```

These classes do follow the Façade pattern.

Comment: Are these classes implementing the facade pattern?

Comment: In some contexts it can make sense, in others not. Who knows your context if not you?

Comment: @Ixrec good question. Yes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would name them based on what the facade does for consumers, or what it needs to "look like" to the outside world. The fact that it is a facade is an implementation-detail.

So instead of, say, `BillingSystemFacade`, I'd present it as a `BillingService`. Heck, perhaps someday I can get rid of whatever clunky API is behind it, and rewrite it from scratch, but the consumers don't need to know whether it is/isn't a facade, only what it promises to do for them.

Comment: Agree.  Your consumers don't care whether it's a facade or not.

Comment: I made an SDK, and some facades class to consume its functionality. For example ‘class ConvertorFacade’, and I provided its singleton instance that named convertor. So, consumer just have to use ‘sdk.convertor.bitmap2jpg’.